# How can I force my count to only count the number of

Tags: count

I'm using SQL in PDQ inventory to generate a report. I'm trying to provide a count of only one set of data, the Display Adapters (Should be between 0 and 4). So some systems have more than one display adapter and we  want that information.
Right now, count is giving us huge numbers, probably counting things I don't want it to.

```
select
    Computers.Name as "Computer Name",
    CPUs.Name,
    Computers.Memory as "RAM",
    HardwareDevices.Name as "Display Adapters",
    count(*)
from Computers, CPUs, HardwareDevices
where (<ComputerFilter> and HardwareDevices.Name like '%this%' and HardwareDevices.ComputerID == Computers.ComputerID)
or (<ComputerFilter> and HardwareDevices.Name like '%that%' and HardwareDevices.ComputerID == Computers.ComputerID)
GROUP BY "Computer Name"
```

These are actually only bring back 0-4 rows. We just want a count of the total rows of both of these and nothing else:

```
  where (<ComputerFilter> and HardwareDevices.Name like '%this%' and HardwareDevices.ComputerID == Computers.ComputerID)
    or (<ComputerFilter> and HardwareDevices.Name like '%that%' and HardwareDevices.ComputerID == Computers.ComputerID)
```

Comment: "counting things I don't want it to" -- you'll need to learn how joins work.

Comment: Instead of old-style `,` cross-joins (which were deprecated 30 years ago), use proper `JOIN...ON...` syntax. At the moment you just have a huge cross-join

Answer (score 2):

It's because you join the table "CPUs" without a single condition in the where -clause.  The result is the lines from computers x hardwaredevices (joined on computerid) x all possible CPUs.

The DB's I know would refuse to run your query, because it lacks "group by" columns.